# filesystemwatcher check last detection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I'm using FileSystemWatcher to monitor my folder in .net and I'm firing Created, Changed and Renamed events.

In Created and Renamed events, `NotifyFilter`is `NotifyFilters.FileName`
In Changed event it is set to `NotifyFilters.LastWrite`

Now.. I want to not fire these events if the last firing was past than 1 second. So every firing have to be delayed of 1 second. This means also that it can skip the files changed/renamed/created between this delay. Just not to do anything while is delayed.

I searched and tried a lot but I couldn't sort it out.

Comment: err.. please specify the problem you're having; provide a code sample of the failing code.

 despite misconceptions, SO is not a tutorial site, nor a community where you can request others to do feature requests and implementations for you. Please take the time to review the **basics** of Delegates, Events, and EventHandling.

Comment: i don't know how to get the time of last fired file and make the delay of one second. my code is a simple filesystemwatcher with the 3 events.

Comment: as @DWRoelands points out below, if your criteria/condition is time, then you'll need two points of time to compare. `DateTime.Now()` and a Variable of your own, which you will assign `DateTime.Now().AddSeconds(+1)` to, if the condition you set is satisfied (true). This doesn't answer your whole question, because you want to keep an event from firing.. that's where OOP comes in and your understanding of Delegates, Events, EventArgs, and EventHandling. the `do stuff` should be your own event that your classes perscribe to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a timestamp that represents the next valid time to process the event.  Then, in the event handlers, check the current time against that time.

```
Public Class MyClass
    Dim NextValidTime as DateTime

    public sub Some_Event_Handler()
        If Now() > NextValidtime Then
            'do stuff
            NextValidTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, 1, Now)
        Else
            ' Not enough time has passed - do nothing
        End If
    end sub
End Class
```

Comment: I stated it in the comments above, but the OP is intending not to raise an event based on those conditions.. so `do stuff` will be a raise event statement following, eventArg declaration in your sample here.